# .NET Web Service / API for BLOB/File Storage

Tags: mongodb, amazon-s3, azure-storage, ravendb, rackspace-cloud

I am looking for an API that performs functionality roughly analogous to Rackspace Cloud Files / OpenStack Swift, Microsoft Azure Blob Storage, or Amazon S3 that can be run on a Windows Server.

I am not speaking of all the add-ons including replication, etc, but an API that enables a similar RESTful API for the storage/serving (including Anonymous). Some examples of functionality I like, and would be missing if I rolled my own right now, are:

- Rackspace's Large Files support.
- Amazon S3's Root Document support.
- Microsoft Azure BLOB storage Page Blobs and Authentication.

Options like MongoDB's GridFS are getting close, but wouldn't quite cut it. RavenDB's "Attachments" functionality is pretty close, I understand it only supports up to 2Gb via the ESENT storage engine

Just to clarify, I'm not exactly sure what form this would take. I'm not looking for a pre-built product (which I don't see exists), but perhaps a stub of a project, an open source project planning to provide this functionality, people who might have developed their own similar solution in C#, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have RavenFS that handles that scenario, I think.
It is a commercial offering, though.

Comment: Looks like an Answer! I should have read back to May on your Blog (Designing RavenFS (http://ayende.com/blog/4828/designing-ravenfs ) and RavenFS & Rsync (http://ayende.com/blog/4829/ravenfs-rsync )). I've posted a bit of background here (http://solutionevangelist.com/post/13313/ ). The only issue is I'd like to use it for a few personal non-commercial projects too which might be a bit price sensitive. However, this may be solvable via a developer license, and I'm sure we'd be able to find paying clients/projects for this. Can you tell me more?